# How to toggle 2 listviews in dockpanel programmatically? [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf

So here is the scenario, In my WPF application I have 2 list view in my dockpanel(Only one listview should visible at a time) each listview view contain different Contextmenu item. I would like to toggle my listview onclick button. How can I do it programmatically?

```
 <Grid>
 <Button Name="toggle" click= "toggle_click"></Button>
 </Grid>

<Dockpanel> 
<Listview>
<ListView.ContextMenu>
.View
.Print
.Send via mail

</ListView.ContextMenu>
</Listview>

<Listview>
<ListView.ContextMenu>
.Add
.Delete
.Modify

</ListView.ContextMenu>
</Listview>
</Dockpanel>
```

Please help as I am new to WPF programming I am struggling a lot to learn it.

Comment: share your full xaml code , Explain more about your requirement

Comment: I would like to use 2 listview in one gridview container. On toggle button click I would like to hide the listview1 and display listview2 (Vice versa). My code exactly same as the above code. please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly you could set the `Visibility` property of the `ListView` elements in your `Click` event handler, e.g.:

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Toggle" Click="toggle_click"></Button>
</Grid>

<DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
    <ListView x:Name="lv1">
        <TextBlock>1</TextBlock>
    </ListView>
    <ListView x:Name="lv2" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <TextBlock>2</TextBlock>
    </ListView>
</DockPanel>
```

---

```
private void toggle_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lv1.Visibility = lv1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
    lv2.Visibility = lv1.Visibility == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: May be its simple. But, you saved me from a biggest headache past 1 hour.